# Protecting against race conditions in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency, redis

I'm experiencing a race condition in Node.js that goes like this:

- Request A arrives, reads the session.
- Request B arrives, reads the session.
- Request B modifies the session, upon end of response writes the session.
- Request A writes the session. Modifications by B are lost.

What are some options for me to address this problem? I'm using Connect with the `session` middleware and `connect-mongo` middleware to store my sessions in MongoDb. I'm open to modifying the middleware as necessary, but I'd prefer to use an existing solution, since I'm not the most experienced programmer when it comes to concurrency issues.

The most important thing for me is that the solution must scale beyond one process. I've looked into various semaphore/mutex possibilities, but none of them seems to scale.

For those who suggest I write my client code around this problem—coding around race conditions has been my M.O. until now, but that's led me to have code that is awkward and breaks easily.

Comment: Concurrency always is a challenge. Have you taken a look at [redis-lock](https://www.npmjs.org/package/redis-lock) ?

Comment: @TwBert thanks very much for that-- hadn't seen that one actually. Or had, and forgot. Same difference :D. Looks like a good option!

Comment: Don't lock the session, create a lock and store it in your session. Check the lock for required action. This way you will serialize the transactions not the requests.

Comment: By storing a lock in the session, do you mean something like a flag that marks the session "read only"?

Comment: Not really, your session should have a flag saying locked. How you chose to act is your decision.You can respond saying request being processed or please wait or it is read only. It is better to have a locking mechanism outside a webserver if you want it to scale.

Comment: Use locks or semaphores!